# Choose Directory for Gradle Generated Source Code

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, dagger, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2 to generate some source code in my Gradle project. Right now those sources are being generated and added in the `./build/classes/main` folder along with all the class files.

1. How do I choose a folder to separate all the generated .java files to?
2. How do I include that folder in my gradle Java project, and have IntelliJ view those as sources so I can use them in my project?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [application plugin](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html) only uses a certain set of directories by default, mixing in flavours of build to decide what files to compile.

However, I did find [an example build script](https://github.com/griffio/dagger2-example) that creates a dagger configuration and manipulates gradle into using it for the generated output and adds it to the classpath. It uses dagger-compiler.

The core of it is:

```
sourceSets {
  dagger {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/dagger/java']
    }
  }
}

configurations {
  compileDagger
}

compileJava {
  description = "dagger annotation processor is loaded automatically from classpath"
  sourceSets.dagger.java.srcDirs*.mkdirs()
  classpath += configurations.compileDagger
  options.compilerArgs += [
      '-s', sourceSets.dagger.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
  ]
}

clean {
  description = "delete files in generated source directory tree"
  delete fileTree(dir: sourceSets.dagger.java.srcDirs.iterator().next())
}

dependencies {
  ext.daggerVersion = "2.0.1"

  compile(
      "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}",
      "com.google.guava:guava:18.0")

  compileDagger(
      "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}")

}
```

Regarding IntelliJ, the plugin should automatically add any srcSets via the normal building of the idea project, so there should be no additional configuration needed, just regenerate it.